# How to create a Notepad++ macro to run multiple plugins automatically?

Tags: macros, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ for different languages i.e: JAVA, C, C++. For each of these languages I have installed plugins to make coding easier in Notepad++.
The problem is that every time I start Notepad++ I have to go and run all those plugins manually. I tried recording a macro so that it will perform all these actions by one click but it didn't record anything I did with the plugins. The macro will record any changes I bring to the code or if I save the code to some other location but it won't record the actions performed by the plugins.
Can anyone guide me to a solutions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a real IDE, such as Netbeans or Eclipse?  They provide a wealth of features and functionality you cannot get in Notepad++ no matter how many plugins you add.  For development, Notepad++ is to Eclipse as a skateboard is to a Ferrari.  I suggest you seriously consider learning an IDE.  Both Eclipse and Netbeans are free.

Comment: I suspect this question might also belong better on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: I have worked with Visual Studio 08,10,12 also Borland C++, Eclipse, Netbeans,IntelliJ IDEA and more. I have Notepad++ in a portable device to carry it with me when I travel. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **AutoHotKey** tool. It can send keystrokes/mouseclicks to Notepad++ so you can easily combine invoking many menu items into one command. (And much more like work with clipboard, ask for values in input boxes, run apps or DLL's.) Please see [AutoHotKey usage with Notepad++ in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220666/in-notepad-change-tab-size-instantly/22880354#22880354).